# how to solve this algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation: $\frac{-a}{2}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-L}})+\frac{3xL}{4}=1$.

I need to get $L$ as a function of $x$, i.e. $L=f(x)$, also $a$ in the above equation is a constant.

I tried to solve this by squaring but I got a cubic equation which I don't want because of the three possible roots. Is there a way to get $f(x)$ without getting a cubic equation. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $L$ supposed to be much smaller than $1$ ?

Comment: Actually, $0<L<1$.

Comment: This one, I was ready to bet it. If it was $L\ll 1$, there are ways to do it.

Comment: Yeah, if that was the case I can take approximations and get the answer but sadly its not.